# "language-learning" tag: Bad idea?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tag-block-request, meta-tags

There are currently 48 questions tagged [language-learning](/questions/tagged/language-learning).

1. 19 of them are closed (~40%).
2. 11 of them are "plz-give-me-teh-resourcez/help-with-teh-resourcez".
3. 9 of them are "I don't get this code explain plz" or "My code doesn't work explain plz".
4. 9 of them are discussion/opinion-like questions that are more suited for Programmers at best (or not suited for any site at worst).

Number 3 is probably okay, but the others seem to suggest the tag generally doesn't exactly inspire confidence in the worthiness of the question. And wasn't the basically-a-synonym [learning](/questions/tagged/learning) gotten rid of some time ago?

Comment: FYI: I voted the closed ones for delete, voted the open and non-constructive or offtopic (programmers.se) ones for close, removed the tag from "real questions". And yes, the tag must be burninated. By the way, I also stumbled upon `exercise` tag in one of the questions. You might want to look at that as well.

Comment: Seems to be meta, [which seems to be actively discouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).